# Show function is absolutely integrable

Tags: integration, functional-analysis

How do you show that the function

$c\cdot(1+|x|)^{-(1+\epsilon)}$

is absolutely integrable? I know you need to show the integral is finite in absolute value, but how does that work in practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_0^{\infty} \frac 1 {(1+x)^{1+\epsilon}}\, dx=(1+x)^{-\epsilon} /{(-\epsilon)}|_0^{\infty}=1/{\epsilon}$. Similarly compute $\int_{-\infty}^{0} \frac 1 {(1+|x|)^{1+\epsilon}}\, dx$ or just use the fact that the integrand is an even function. Hence if $f$ is the given function then $\int|f(x)|\, dx=2|c|/{\epsilon}$.

Comment: I am wondering how did you get
$(1+x)^{(-\epsilon)}$ instead of $\frac{-(1+x)^{-\epsilon}}{\epsilon}$ ?
Does have to do with the fact we assume $\epsilon$ is really small ?

Comment: @Crash Thanks for pointing out. I have corrected the mistake.